# Control inside datatemplate in ListBox UWP xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a ListBox consist of Datatemplate.
Here is my code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" SelectionChanged="MyListBox_SelectionChanged_1"  SelectionMode="Single" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Rectangle Width="50" Height="45" Name="myRectangle"  Fill="DodgerBlue" />
       <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightGreen" Height="22" Width="22" />
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Initials}" x:Name="PersonInitials" />
       <stackpanel>
       <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="person_lbl" Text="{Binding SourceLink}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
       <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="detail_lbl" Text="{Binding ConversationId}" Foreground="DarkSlateGray"/>
       </StackPanel>
      <ToggleSwitch OffContent=" "/>
   </DataTemplate>           
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Datatemplate consist of rectangle,Ellipse,3 textblocks and toggle switch which finally give an output like this as shown in image.
[This is the template I will get.Please ignore the search bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQg9.png)
Now Here is my Query:

I want to perform action on the basis of **selection of a data_template** in the listBox in which it should fetch the text of the  textbox and display it somewhere.After searching about it on internet I have only found the examples like

```
<listbox>item1</listbox>
```

My ListBox does not consist of only one item it has many items that is making a template.
How can I fetch one textbox element on selection of whole template.Does anyone has idea how do so?
This is my code in c#:

```
    class ReadJsonData
    {
        public List<Information> information { get; set; }
        public ReadJsonData()
        {
            information = new List<Information>();

        }
    }
    public class Information
    {
        public string SourceLink { get; set; }
        public int ConversationId { get; set; }
        public string Initials { get; set; }
    }
 and this is on MainPage.xaml
    public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            JsonReader();

        }
        public async void JsonReader()
        {
            Information infos = new Information();
            infos.ConversationId = 1122;
            infos.Initials = "LM";
            infos.SourceLink = "abc";
            Information info1 = new Information();
            info1.ConversationId = 111;
            info1.Initials = "MM";
            info1.SourceLink = "pqr";
            Information info2 = new Information();
            info2.ConversationId = 1113;
            info2.Initials = "NM";
            info2.SourceLink = "vrl";
            ReadJsonData rb = new ReadJsonData();
            rb.information.Add(infos);
            rb.information.Add(info1);
            rb.information.Add(info2);
            var rb1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rb);
            var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadJsonData>(rb1);

            foreach (var info in rootobject.information)
            {
                MyListBox.ItemsSource = rootobject.information;

            }
        private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,
        SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = sender as Information;
            string initials = selectedItem.Initials;
            show_initial = initials;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting the item source of the `ListBox` (MyListBox) to a list of items of your model class (`List<SomeClassName>`)..

If your model class is something like this :

```
public class SomeClassName
    {
        public string Initials { get; set; }
        public string SourceLink { get; set; }
        public string ConversationId { get; set; }
    }
```

You can add this code to the `OnSelectionChanged` or `Tapped` event of your listbox to get the data members of the class:

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
   var selectedItem = sender as SomeClassName;
   //Gives you the Initials of the selected list item
   string intials = selectedItem.Initials;
}
```

Hope this helps..!

---

EDIT 1 :

First of all why are you iterating `rootobject.information`? you can simply use it as item source without the for loop..

```
foreach (var info in rootobject.information)
{
   MyListBox.ItemsSource = rootobject.information;    
}
```

Second, what does this line do ? `show_initial = initials;` is show_initial a variable ? what does it do ?

---

Edit 2 :

```
private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(MyListBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
      var selectedItem = sender as Information;
      //Gives you the Initials of the selected list item
      string intials = selectedItem.Initials;
    } else {
      Debug.WriteLine("No item Selected");
    }
}
```

Please check if the `MyListBox.SelectedItem != null` condition is satisfied or not.

Comment: Thankyou for help!.But it is not working out. I tried putting value of initials in a textblock,but it does not fetch value of initial..

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions ? if not, try debugging your code and check what is the value that you are getting in `selectedItem` variable..Also, it would be easier for me if you could add your model class to the question..

Comment: I have added my code in the question.Please check that out.

Comment: Yes,@pratyay thanks for the correction."MyListBox.ItemsSource = rootobject.information" it can be used without foreach .and yea show_initial is a variable where I was checking while degugging whether it contain initials or not but it does not contain anything and also in my code "  MyListBox_SelectionChanged" does not fier.

Comment: So that must be the problem .. your listbox selection changed event is not getting fired .. please check if Tapped or any other event is getting fired or not on the listview

Comment: After checking I found,'MyListBox_SelectionChanged' is getting fired.But   ' var selectedItem = sender as SomeClassName;'  selectedItem value is null and 'selectedItem.Initials' is throwing null reference exception.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. if you want we could do a screen share so that I can identify what is causing the issue..

Comment: Hey @Pratyay thanx a lot for helping how and where can i contact you for xaml queries?